Bake selected constraints relatively to the parent?
I need to store an animation of the object while preserving its dependencies to the parent. The object is connected to the bone using the Child Of constraint. I transferred some animation to it using the Copy Transforms constraint. How do I bake the Copy Transforms but keep the Child Of? So if I turn off the "Child of" I will have an animation playing in 0;0 coordinates.
